# I don't get why this answer is in the audit queue

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, disputed-review-audits, specific-answer

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20109067) ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568002/react-native-run-android-could-not-find-common-jar-android-arch-corecommon)) because I downvoted the answer. Sure, it answers the post, but it also links to another question, which asks the same question and the solution is the same as the audit-answer provides, so this is a typical candidate for a duplicate.

Why is such an answer in a review queue? Can this be removed to don't frustrate future reviewers?

---

[image]

Comment: It's an audit because it was upvoted multiple times and never downvoted. By downvoting the answer outside of the review queue, you'll remove that answer the audit pool.

Comment: 8 upvotes for that question and 16 upvotes for that answer... all in less than a month. I guess some tags are more _generous_ than others.

Comment: Too bad that I am now excluded from the review queues for a few days. Unfortunately, this kind of thing isn't uncommon.

Comment: A mod may want to remove the review ban, although those are not handed for a single failure. While this audit was certainly bad, you may need to change your approach if you find yourself failing audits with some frequency. Audits are chosen automatically, so a few bad apples are bound to exist as voting/flagging patterns are not always easy to predict.

Comment: Maybe a mod is merciful ;)

Yup, I failed another review today, but this was my fault, however I reviewed about 3 month without failures and because of one mistake and one false positive, a temporary ban is annoying.

Comment: I would stay away from some tags. Android is known to attract much upvotes, as is regex. Use a filter so you only review stuff you're comfortable with.

Comment: @yivi that's not   good reason to downvote a post.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, I don't agree. The OP already tried downvoting from within the queue, and complained the post was a bad audit. I think downvoting in this case is both a good solution and coherent with what the OP attempted to do in the first place.

Comment: @yivi there's nothing wrong with the answer. So down voting is bad

Comment: @YvetteColomb, that's your opinion, which you are entitled to.

Comment: @yivi no it's not an opinion, it's how the site works and how it recommends we vote

Comment: @YvetteColomb: _"there's nothing wrong with the answer"_: This is is very much an opinion, in my opinion.

Comment: @yivi it's not in a tag you frequent, so why would you be so keen to make that assumption?

Comment: @Yvette. I'm not sure why you feel this is a bone to pick, and why you are so keen on pushing this. I can form my own opinions, and have no need to justify them. As you aren't justifying yours, which is fine as well.

Comment: @yivi you are suggesting to people to do something I see as wrong. The reviewer has a poor track record and to go and downvote posts to remove them from audits is not the right reason to downvote.

Comment: @Yvette, but you are already past that discussion. Now you wanted to argue if the answer deserving down-voting, if there was _"anything wrong"_ with it. Which seems a silly argument to have, IMO. My take is: downvoting solely to remove something from the audit pool even if you feel it doesn't deserve downvoting? Wrong. (Which is what I guess you are trying to say). Downvoting something you think it deserves downvoting to help improve the audit system? Good (Which is what I'm trying to say).

Comment: I don't think the link is so problematic, but what I find really problematic about that answer is the screenshot of code.

Comment: I also agree with that the link to the other post is "*ok*" but screenshots of code are not, if screenshots of code are hated upon so much it gets questions closed why is this any different for answers?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint If an answer consists entirely re-spouting an answer linked in the same post, but poorly (e.g. with a screenshot of code), I do not consider that a useful answer. The answerer could have pointed to the duplicate directly, in a comment/flag instead of reposting the answer there. At least, that's how I see it.

Comment: @yivi I think I wasn't clear, when I said links to answers being ok, I meant the link providing context and providing more content

Comment: Without the screenshot, the answer is short but complete. The shortness comes from the fact that the question has an easy answer. it might not be easy to determine if this is the case from the review queue, so clicking out to examine it in context would have been warranted. *With* that image, however, it does look like a poor answer, as at a glance it looks like instead of adding code they added an image of code, which is worth a downvote. I think the reason why they used the image was to capture the line number, which was important to the solution. Hard, but valid, audit imho.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The posts chosen for the review audits are selected automatically based on heuristics within the review code base. It's not possible to remove upvoted posts from the review audits. It is possible to exclude lower quality posts from the audits by clearing low quality, spam and rude/abusive flags from posts.

I wouldn't recommend down voting a post to remove it from the review audits (as suggested in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370024/i-dont-get-why-this-answer-is-in-the-audit-queue#comment603044_370024)), because you failed the audit.

Your review history has not been successful, with regular review bans due to audit failures. This would suggest you need to reflect upon your reviewing skills and try to determine where you're going wrong. The problem was less with the post and more with your reviewing skills, as the post gave an explanation, a link for further information and a screen shot. Nothing to indicate low quality or spam.

Comment: @Tim it's just vetting posts, are they an answer? are they a link only? Check for spam. Is it in English. Keep trying, you're getting there. :)

Comment: Since when is an image of code considered a good thing?

Comment: @AndréKool Read my comment here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370024/i-dont-get-why-this-answer-is-in-the-audit-queue#comment603392_370024 the code needed to answer the question is included in the answer: *I found this solution and works for me: add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` in line 18 in file `android/build.gradle`* The image is superfluous, or it shows the added line in context with a line number, the one mentioned in the answer.